Can sharing code on GitHub enhance career opportunities post-PhD?
I am a third year PhD student. If I do projects and upload in a github profile; will it help in my academic career or job hunting after my phd?
I am asking this because if it does increase the worth of our CV. Then its another form of academic currency that I can work on during my free time that can help me in future.
Thank you.

The short answer is yes: sharing your code benefits the community and enhances your CV for both academia and industry.
However, Git is a version control tool that allows you to develop code and collaborate efficiently. It is not meant to be used only to upload your code when it's finished. When I applied for jobs outside academia interviewers often viewed my GitHub profile and asked questions about my projects. They were interested in whether I could effectively use this tool to develop code collaboratively. If I had only uploaded code there, they would have noticed it because of the commit frequency.
Therefore, I encourage you to really learn how to integrate version control on your research - it is good for science and for your career prospects.

Thabk you so much.

@Robin my pleasure. If I answered your question effectively, please consider accepting this answer as best answer. :)
